# (Possibly fictional) Can you locate this mysterious Project Orion design with NERVA engines as RCS?

Tags: engines, design, nuclear-pulse-propulsion, nuclear-propulsion

Some years ago, I happened to see a drawing of a hypothetical Project Orion (the Nuclear Pulse Propulsion one) type spaceship, that had the notable (and highly questionable, IMO) feature of having a brace of NERVA-style solid-core nuclear thermal rockets used as vernier engines and RCS. There were at least 8 engines, I am reasonably sure they pointed both forwards and backwards, and they were typical nozzle-on-reactor NERVA-style engines, not ducted or turret-gimballed. Other than this rather 'remarkable' RCS, it was a fairly conventional bullet-shaped Orion spacecraft.

I don't remember where I saw this drawing, what context it was in, the name of the spacecraft, or any other details. It may have been in a science-fictional (or highly speculative) context, or it may not. It may not have been American.

It was *not* the space battleship from the novel Footfall by Niven and Pournelle -- that did have a form of nuclear thermal RCS, but doesn't match any of the rest of my description.